# Remove File Delete Permission

Tags: lightning, files

I have googled a lot but do not found any supportive document for guidance. I have a standard Files upload option under Task(Standard) object. We have a scenario like users will not have permission to delete the file. But I do not find any way to remove this delete Option from UI.[image]

Please suggest.

Comment: You have to write a trigger for it onDelete on ContentDocument

Comment: @PranayJaiswal You should post it as an answer - not comment :)

Answer (score -1):

Have you set up the user in question permissions correctly?

Setup -> Manage Users -> Users -> Find the users and click on their profile -> System Permissions -> 'Edit Tasks' and then revoke edit access like so by unchecking the checkbox: [image]

Comment: Hi Harry, but this user can edit the task. Need to prevent file deletion only.
Also, I tried to uncheck Edit Tasks Permission on his profile, User still able to delete the file.

Comment: answer is not working